# Access CHATS label with Gmail API

Tags: gmail, chat, google-talk, gmail-api

Does Gmail API provide a way to fetch Gmail chat logs? Chats is a label just like INBOX. I expected to find it in [Users:label list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels) but its not present.

Is there something I have to enable to allow CHATS label to show up? Is this feature  supported in Gmail API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Find timestamp for hangout and chat messages retrieved with gmail api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316138/find-timestamp-for-hangout-and-chat-messages-retrieved-with-gmail-api) , the fact that chats show up in the Gmail API at all is a bug, not a feature. They are likely leaving it out of the list of labels intentionally.

From that answer, I'm inferring that accessing google hangouts history via the API is unsupported, and the ability to do so may disappear in the future.