# Retrieve inline images from gmail api?

Tags: gmail-api

I'm retrieving messages from my Gmail using Gmail API. specifically, the email with Hangouts conversations using this url: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=in:chats

When I enter in a message, I see this structure

```
 {
  "id": "1555561f7b8e1sdf56b",
  "threadId": "155552511dfsd83ce98",
  "labelIds": [
    "CHAT"
  ],
  "snippet": "df",
  "historyId": "270812",
  "internalDate": "1466016331704",
  "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "\"Oscar J. Irún\" <Oscarjiv91@gmail.com>"
      }
    ],
    "body": {
      "size": 2,
      "data": "ZGY="
    }
  },
  "sizeEstimate": 100
}
```

as you can see, the body message is "df". Everything it's ok so far.

The problem comes when the Hangout message is an image. The `snippet` field is empty, and it doesnt show any attachment in the message. This is an example:

```
{
  "id": "155558233274d78c91",
  "threadId": "15fd5552511d83ce98",
  "labelIds": [
    "CHAT"
  ],
  "snippet": "",
  "historyId": "27sd0827",
  "internalDate": "1466018445133",
  "payload": {
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "\"Oscar J. Irún\" <Oscarjiv91@gmail.com>"
      }
    ],
    "body": {
      "size": 0,
      "data": ""
    }
  },
  "sizeEstimate": 100
}
```

I need to retrieve this inline images. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what exactly is your question? are you asking how to get the URL of the image?

Comment: Sorry, yes @WoodrowBarlow. Edited my question

Comment: Getting chat messages through the Gmail API is [not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316138/find-timestamp-for-hangout-and-chat-messages-retrieved-with-gmail-api), so getting attachments is probably not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve attachments by using [`Users.messages.attachments:get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get). Take note that this request requires authorization. All requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. Gmail uses the [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) protocol for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/messageId/attachments/id

public static void getAttachments(Gmail service, String userId, String messageId)
throws IOException {
Message message = service.users().messages().get(userId, messageId).execute();
List<MessagePart> parts = message.getPayload().getParts();
for (MessagePart part : parts) {
if (part.getFilename() != null && part.getFilename().length() > 0) {
String filename = part.getFilename();
String attId = part.getBody().getAttachmentId();
MessagePartBody attachPart = service.users().messages().attachment().
get(userId, messageId, attId).execute();
byte[] fileByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(attachPart.getData());
FileOutputStream fileOutFile =
new FileOutputStream("directory_to_store_attachments" + filename);
fileOutFile.write(fileByteArray);
file OutFile.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is with the Hangouts messages. It appears empty, with no attachments or anything. This works for a normal email retrieved with Gmail API, but it doesn't with Hangouts messages.

Answer (score 0):

JUST FYI for PHP the solution is something similar to this: 
base64_decode(strtr($gmail->service->users_messages_attachments->get('me', $message->id, $arrPart['body']['attachmentId'])->data,'-_', '+/'));