# Messages under "CHAT" label are not displayed using gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

Chat messages were actually displayed using [Users.messages:list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) before a week or two. But now no messages are displayed under CHAT label. Has google stopped displaying CHAT messages or am I missing something. I dint code, but just checked with [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it). Please do let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523712/access-chats-label-with-gmail-api

Comment: okay.. But will there be any other way to access those chat messages other than gmail API ?

Comment: I believe this has been fixed.  Can you verify that they appear now?

Comment: Yeah.. I checked.It was fixed before a couple of days. Thanks for your response