# Can't get Google Chat messages with Gmail API

Tags: chat, gmail-api, google-hangouts, google-chat-api

What are the details of your problem?
Until recently, in my own web application, I used the Gmail API to retrieve Google Chat messages as follows.
I was able to get it from "Label: CHAT" by executing as follows.

(1) Acquisition of thread ID belonging to CHAT label
https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?labelIds=CHAT

(2) Get message information from thread ID
[https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/[Thread](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/%5BThread) ID]

However, it seems that it has been impossible to obtain it since around December 2022, and when I searched for "in: chats" in Gmail, the messages after December 10th were not displayed.

Any method is fine, so I would like to be able to get Google Chat messages as before.
Anyone know the cause and solution?

Please check.

I also tried using the Google Chat API to see if it was possible to get messages, but I could only get messages in the space, and I couldn't get direct messages, so I wasn't able to use it.

I checked all the messages in the labels that can be obtained at "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels", but it seems that chat messages are not included.

Also, in another answer, there was a description that the state included in the Gmail API was a bug, so it is possible that this bug was adapted and it was not displayed, but in that case, there is another way to deal with it. Are you there?
[Access CHATS label with Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523712/access-chats-label-with-gmail-api)

Comment: All i can say about that is your right the last message i have is Dec 16 2022.   Now let me see if i can figure out who at google to contact about this.